# Store credentials for twine upload of artifacts

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pypi, twine

I'm building my python package using Azure DevOps pipeline and the generated artifact is then uploaded to a feed. Everything is working fine, however, I don't like the fact that I have a `.pypirc` file containing the credentials for the upload sitting in my repository.

Basically I'm uploading the artifact using:

```
- script: 'twine upload -r imglib --config-file .pypirc dist/imglib-*.tar.gz'
```

Is there another way to store the credentials, preferably not in a file that anyone could edit? I read something about storing the credentials in the key vault, but I don't see how change the pipeline (the yml file) to do this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Shaykis answere seems to be the right way, however, I'm not able to replace the placeholder in the .pypirc file using a bash command. All I get is three asterics when I print the content of .pypirc after replacement. For the replacement I use:

```
- script: 'sed -i "s/__password__/$PYPI_CRED_MAPPED/g" .pypirc'
  displayName: 'Setting PyPI credentials'
  env:
    PYPI_CRED_MAPPED: $(pypi_cred)
```

The content of .pypirs is (displayed during the build task using a bash `cat .pypirc`. Is there an easier way to debug the build prozess?):

```
[distutils]
Index-servers =
  pypi
  imglib

[imglib]
Repository = https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/_packaging/imglib/pypi/upload
username = imglib
password = ***
```

Does anyone know what is happening there?

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried to use `$env:PYPI_CRED_MAPPED` but in that case only the $env is replaced by nothing and all I'm left with is `:PYPI_CRED_MAPPED`. Also, I look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) and they use the variable directly (e.g. `$PYPI_CRED_MAPPED`, see bottom of page).

**EDIT 3:**

The three asterics are just a placeholder. It worked with `$PYPI_CRED_MAPPED` as mentioned in **EDIT 2**. The build process was failing because of another reason. I also tried it with the powershell command provided in the answer and it worked as well. So thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the variable as a secret variable, in the `.pypirc` file put a placeholder and in the pipeline add a script that replace the placeholder with the variable.

1) In the `.yaml` editor click on the 3 dots near the Save/Run button on the top right and then click "Variables".

2) Add a new variable (`pythonCred` fore example) with the password and click on the lock icon to make it secret.

3) Go to your `.pypirc` file and replace the password with `__password__`.

4) In your pipeline add a PowerShell task to put the password:

```
- powershell: |
    (Get-Content path/to/pypirc) -replace "__password__" , "$env:CredPython" | Set-Content -Path path/to/pypirc
  env: CredPython: $(pythonCred) # you must to map the variable because is a secret variable
```

You can also use Azure Key Vault with this way, download the password from there in with Azure Key Vault task and replace update the `.pypirc` file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible. However, I will rewrite this to a bash task.

Comment: Good idea, is not a complicated task :)

Comment: I just updated the question to incorporate your answer. Are you able to help me regarding the bash command?

Comment: In the `sed` - instead of `$(variable)` use `$env:variable`